# CSS Background Image Flickering After Transition

Tags: html, css

Just want to start off by saying that I know questions like this have been asked and I've looked at all the ones I could find on the first few pages of google with no luck.

**Problem:**

I have a landing page with a div that stretches the width of the screen and is using a CSS transition to fade between 5 different images. They are all of equal size and aspect ratio so I know it can't be a problem with that. The cross fade between the images is smooth but once the transition is done, they flicker then that transition to the next image starts (smoothly again).

**Some things I've done to try and fix it:**

- Saved all the images to reference locally
- Resized all the images to have the same size and aspect ratio
- Added a simple image preload script in JS (*Found in an answer*)
- Gave more time between transitions to allow some load time leniency
- Scaled down all the images in case they were loading slow due to file size
- Tried in Firefox, Opera, and Edge with same problem (*With added browser specific attributes*)

I'm not sure what to do at this point but I know there are smarter people out there that will probably have a solution so I would like to thank the people who offer suggestions in advanced for giving me a hand.

```css
/*** CSS For .container **/

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100% !important;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*** CSS For .container-slideshow ***/

.container-slideshow {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  animation: animSlideshow 28s ease infinite;
}


/*** CSS Animation ***/

@keyframes animSlideshow {
  0% {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600');
  }
  25% {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports');
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600/city');
  }
  75% {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600/animals');
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600/people');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container white-text container-slideshow">

  <div class="container-content">
    <h1>Welcome to Lorem Impsum,</h1>
    <h3>This is just some sample text.</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

It only does the flickering the first time through the animation so I'm guessing it has something to do with changing the background image to an unloaded picture. Is doing it in this example for me at least. (If it isn't for anyone else I gonna take it as a hardware issue on my end)

Here is a screen shot from my end just in case I'm the only one who sees it:
[Gyazo GIF](https://gyazo.com/0b7c194777532670fd896aeee52887b2)

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this from the code you've given. https://jsbin.com/qikumejozu/1/edit?html,css,output works fine for me. Could you provide a minimum working example showing the problem?

Comment: @Zac Edited to add example

Answer (score 1):

From what I can assume between the 100% and the going back to 0% there's no background, I would recommend that you add your initial background at 100% and add one more step to the process that way it'll just start over.

Something like:

```css
@keyframes animSlideshow {
    0% {
        background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600');
    }
    20% {
        background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports');
    }
    40% {
        background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600/city');
    }
    60% {
        background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600/animals');
    }
    80% {
        background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600/people');
    }
    100% {
        background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/600');
    }
}
```

This way it ends where it started and you wouldn't notice a blink.

Comment: The flicker happens during the animation. But I will for sure do that cause it will at least fix that harsh transition at the end. Thanks!

Comment: What I saw is that it happens from 100% to 0%, basically when the animation restarts. You could play with the percantages.

Comment: Is it also possible that the image hasn't loaded yet?

Comment: Check edit I added new stuff a little bit ago that talks about that, I added a GIF of the issue. I'm guessing that is what it is, so I'm going to write a better JS image preloader to see if that can sort the issue. Thanks for the fast responses!

Comment: I am pretty sure that's an image loading issue. Check your network tab and see if the flicker coincides with the image loading. Also in this case the images are remote which causes slower loading because of the HTTP request.